# I get "invalid id" when using the new fileDelete to remove a file from the admin page

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I've been able to make a script to save a file using the new fileCreate but when I try to delete a file with fileDelete, I can't seems to get the right ID.

```js
mutation fileDelete($fileIds: [ID!]!) {
     fileDelete(fileIds: $fileIds) {
          userErrors {
            field
            message
          }
          deletedFileIds
    }
}
```

I pass the ID from my last image: "gid://shopify/ImageSource/20805776113730", called with a new private app key (which should use the v2021-10)

If anybody got that mutation to work, I would appreciate any help.

Response from Shopify:

```
{
    "data": {
        "fileDelete": null
    },
    "errors": [{
        "message": "invalid id",
        "locations": [{
            "line": 3,
            "column": 4
        }],
        "path": ["fileDelete"]
    }],
    "extensions": {
        "cost": {
            "requestedQueryCost": 10,
            "actualQueryCost": 1,
            "throttleStatus": {
                "maximumAvailable": 1000,
                "currentlyAvailable": 999,
                "restoreRate": 50
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what's send:

```
{
    "query": "mutation fileDelete($fileIds: [ID!]!) {\r\n\t\t\tfileDelete(fileIds: $fileIds) {\r\n\t\t\t  userErrors {\r\n\t\t\t\tfield\r\n\t\t\t\tmessage\r\n\t\t\t  }\r\n\t\t\t  deletedFileIds\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t  }",
    "variables": {
        "fileIds": "gid:\/\/shopify\/ImageSource\/20825330909250"
    }
 }
```

Comment: Best you share some results. Error messages are usually pretty clear about what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the ImageMedia ID:

```
{
    "fileIds": "gid://shopify/MediaImage/20835931816073"
}
```

To get that ID, you need to send your request like this:

```
{
  files(first: 99, reverse:true){
    edges{
      cursor
      node{
        ... on MediaImage {
          id
          mimeType
          image {
            originalSrc
          }
        }
        __typename
        createdAt
        fileStatus
        preview{
          image{
            altText
            id
            transformedSrc
            originalSrc
          }
          status
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "files": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "cursor": "xxxxxx",
          "node": {
            "id": "gid:\/\/shopify\/MediaImage\/xxxx",
            "mimeType": "image\/png",
            "image": {
              "originalSrc": "xxxx"
            },
            "__typename": "MediaImage",
            "createdAt": "2021-10-21T17:39:58Z",
            "fileStatus": "READY",
            "preview": {
              "image": {
                "altText": "xxxx",
                "id": "gid:\/\/shopify\/ImageSource\/xxxx",
                "transformedSrc": "xxxx",
                "originalSrc": "xxxx"
              },
              "status": "READY"
            }
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "cost": {
      "requestedQueryCost": 398,
      "actualQueryCost": 18,
      "throttleStatus": {
        "maximumAvailable": 1000.0,
        "currentlyAvailable": 982,
        "restoreRate": 50.0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Elvis, I didn't know about that section ' ... on MediaImage {', it gives me now access to the right ID, thank for your help ! Looks like I was trying to delete with the preview ID.